# Update / change  store of list component sencha touch

Tags: list, sencha-touch, store

I have an overlay that has a toolbar as a dockedItem and a Ext.List as an item.
This overlay is shown as the user drags the slider to show the important things in each card I have in a carousel. Each card has its own store with data I want to show in the overlay.

I am able to change the toolbar's title while I drag:

```
this.overlayTb.setTitle(cards[index].categoryName);
```

but when I try to change the store that feeds my list view, it does work.

```
this.myList.store = cards[index].store;
```

It just keeps showing the data of the initial store I set up instead of changing, like the toolbar title does.
I have tried calling doLayout() on myList and Ext.StoreMgr.get('newsStore').load(); as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112237/sencha-touch-refresh-list-store), but no good came out of that. And if I try:

```
this.myList.update();
```

it stops showing the data of the store, and I can only see a blank panel

While debugging, I can see that this.myList.store changes to the store I need, but the view is not updating.

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **bindStore(cards[index].store)** method of the Ext.List which properly destroys and cleans up after the old store and binds the new store to the List's events.