# How to refresh DataView'data rendering in Sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I add a dataview in an carousel form and it shows up as a list. Then I delete several items of the dataview, but the list in carousel view doesn't change. What should I do to refresh the view?

I have tried several methods such as 'remove()', 'removeAll()', 'destroy()', 'refresh()', but it has no effect.

Model:

```
Ext.define('Chihiro.model.User', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: [ 'id', 'name', 'nickname', 'signiture', 'gender', 'birthday', 'school', 'job', 'portrait', 'interests', 'dis'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'friends'
    },
    autoLoad: true
}
});
```

dataview:

```
Ext.define('Chihiro.view.userlist.List', {
extend: 'Ext.DataView',
xtype: 'userlist',

store: {
    model: 'Chihiro.model.User'
},
config: {
    ui:'loans',
    useComponents: true,
    defaultType: 'listitem',
    emptyText: '<div style="margin-top: 20px; text-align: center">没有找到任何人哦</div>',
    deselectOnContainerClick: false
}
});
```

Panel:

```
Ext.define('Chihiro.view.contact.List', {
extend: 'Ext.Carousel',

xtype: 'contactpanel',
id: 'contactnavigationview',

layout: 'vbox',
config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    //autoDestroy: false,
    scrollable: true,
    //defaultBackButtonText: '返回',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: '好友'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Comment: Do you have a store bound to your DataView? If so, changing items in your data store should refresh the view automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to re-load the store in order to refresh the dataview.

Methods like `remove()`, `removeAll()`, `destroy()` and `refresh()` will definitely won't have any effect.

When you change the items inside a store, you need to call `load()` method on your datastore. This will essentially refresh your dataview.

```
yourStoreForDataView.load();
```

Useful Post : [**Sencha-touch : refresh list : store**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112237/sencha-touch-refresh-list-store)

Comment: Thanks a lot but there is still a problem. I use localstorage as the proxy of the model, and when I call load of the store, there is an error.